# How to determine type in disk file before reading to ArrayList?

Tags: java

If I read a file using

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(diskFile));
```

How, after that, would I be able to determine which type it is so I can read it into an arraylist of the same type? It's easier to do when you know which type it is such as int

```
do {
    nextInt = in.nextInt();
    n.add(nextInt);     
}while(in.hasNextInt() == true);
```

but if I don't know if the file type is String, int, double, etc. How would I be able to add them to an ArrayList of the same type? So my solution would be to figure out the type before adding it to an ArrayList, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: When you say "type of file" do you really mean the "contents of the file"? Because there is no such thing as a String file or an int file, etc...

Comment: Are you the one who creates the file?  Also, is it always going to be a primitive type or a String, and not some other object?

Comment: In the general sense, there is no way to do what you are asking about.  File content is not fundamentally "typed" that way.  If you don't have control (or at least knowledge) over how the file was written, the best you can do is read it into strings, and then try to parse those strings as various types.

Comment: @csm_dev that's what I meant. Is there a way that I can check the type of the values in the array before I add them to the ArrayList?

Comment: @DM yes, assuming that it's going to be an int, double, or String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a single unknown value per line in your input file, I'd recommend you read it as a String and then test the string value using the simple parsers available with the common types.  You can test by catching exceptions.  Here is an example for Integer.

```
        int newData = 0;
        boolean haveInt = true;
        try {
                 newData = Integer.parseInt(theInputString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            haveInt = false;
        }
        if (haveInt) {
           intArrayList.add(newData);
        }
```